# Unity Authentication for Android - SignInWithGoogleAsync Throws Permission Denied

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, google-play-services, permission-denied

I'm sure I'm missing something silly but after I retrieve and pass the google id token to Unity Authentication I get the errors:

**[Authentication]: Request failed: 401, {"title":"PERMISSION_DENIED","detail":"validation failed","details":[],"status":401}**

**WebRequestException: {"title":"PERMISSION_DENIED","detail":"validation failed","details":[],"status":401}**

Below is my code, any help appreciated:

```
async void Awake()
     {
         await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();
         InitializePlayGamesLogin();
     }
 
     void InitializePlayGamesLogin()
     {
         PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
     }
 
     // Call when login button is pressed
     public void LoginGooglePlayGames()
     {       
         Social.localUser.Authenticate(OnGooglePlayGamesLogin);
     }
 
     //Check login success
     async void OnGooglePlayGamesLogin(bool success)
     {
         if (success)
         {
             // Call Unity Authentication SDK to sign in or link with Google.
             string idToken = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserId();
             await SignInWithGoogleAsync(idToken);                          
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.Log("Unsuccessful login");
         }
     }
 
     async Task SignInWithGoogleAsync(string idToken)
     {
         try
         {
             await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInWithGoogleAsync(idToken);
             Debug.Log("SignIn is successful.");
             //if sign in successful turn off login screen.
             loginScreen.SetActive(false);
         }
         catch (AuthenticationException ex)
         {
             // Compare error code to AuthenticationErrorCodes
             // Notify the player with the proper error message
             Debug.LogException(ex);
         }
         catch (RequestFailedException ex)
         {
             // Compare error code to CommonErrorCodes
             // Notify the player with the proper error message
             Debug.LogException(ex);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Too late now, but as I'm reading your post I'm thinking the issue is that your passing an authorization token you retrieve from Google Play Games but you're trying to sign in with Google. Signing in with GPG and Google are two different things. Use SignInWithGooglePlayGames instead.

I happen to read your 7 months old post because I've lately got the same error when trying to authenticate with Google Play Games. But my issue was that I was using the same token twice: firstly by trying to log in and secondly to sign in in case the login resulted in the "already linked to another player" exception. I had to request a new token before calling the Unity-GPG link for the second time.

I hope this can help others, as there's not much literature online about this.